# Filling the default value of a dropdown in a gridview with the current value

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, dropdownbox

After some lengthy experimentation, I discovered that having this line of code on the aspx side:

```
<EditItemTemplate>  
    <asp:DropDownList ID="ddl_Project_Owner" runat="server" Width="70px" 
         DataTextField="Project_Owner" DataValueField="Project_Owner" 
         SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Project_Owner") %>' >
    </asp:DropDownList>  
</EditItemTemplate>
```

caused an index error, but removing the `SelectedValue='<%# Bind("Project_Owner") %>'` piece allowed the gridview to function properly.  The only thing is, when the row goes into edit mode, the dropdown is not filled with the current value.  It's blank.  I'd like to fill it with the current value.

On the code-behind side, I use this code to fill the dropdown:

```
protected void DataGrid_ResourceAllocation_EditCommand(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
{
    DataGrid_ResourceAllocation.EditRowStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightYellow;
    DataGrid_ResourceAllocation.EditIndex = e.NewEditIndex;
    LoadResourceAllocationGrid();
    //DataGrid_ResourceAllocation.DataBind();


    SqlConnection conn = GetConnection();
    int RAC = DataGrid_ResourceAllocation.Rows.Count;

    GridViewRow row = DataGrid_ResourceAllocation.Rows[e.NewEditIndex];

    //*********************************************************
    //******** Fill in all your dropdown lists here ***********
    //*********************************************************

    DropDownList ddList = row.FindControl("ddl_Project_Owner") as DropDownList;
    string ddListVal = ddList.SelectedValue;

    //DropDownList ddList = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("ddl_Project_Owner");
    if (ddList != null)
    {
        //bind dropdown-list
        string sqlStr = "Select distinct Project_Owner from tblProjectHealth order by Project_Owner";
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();

        conn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStr, conn);
        SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        ad.Fill(ds);

        ddList.DataSource = ds;
        ddList.DataTextField = "Project_Owner";
        ddList.DataValueField = "Project_Owner";
        ddList.DataBind();

        //DataRowView dr = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;
        //ddList.SelectedItem.Text = dr["category_name"].ToString();
        ddList.SelectedValue = ddListVal;
    }

}
```

I tried that "ddListVal" variable because I thought it might work, but it didn't, so you can ignore that.

Can anyone help me get my dropdown to populate with the current value that exists for that field in that record?

Answer (score 1):

This error is due to this : you set selectedValeue befor binding dropdownlist.
you can bind dropdownlist in RowDataBound

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            DropDownList ddList= e.Row.FindControl("ddl_Project_Owner") as DropDownList;
            if (ddList != null)
            {
                string sqlStr = "Select distinct Project_Owner from tblProjectHealth order by Project_Owner";
                DataSet ds = new DataSet();

                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlStr, conn);
                SqlDataAdapter ad = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                ad.Fill(ds);

                ddList.DataSource = ds;
                ddList.DataTextField = "Project_Owner";
                ddList.DataValueField = "Project_Owner";
                ddList.DataBind();


            }
        }
    }
```